# Scala collect elements from a complex type

Tags: scala

I have two Maps which contains a String as the key and a List of a certain object type as the value.

```
val map1 = Map[String, List[TypeA]]
val map2 = Map[String, List[TypeA]]
```

TypeA is defined as:

```
case class TypeA(String, TypeB)

trait TypeB
case class LowerB(value: Integer) extends TypeB
case class UpperB(value: Integer) extends TypeB
```

What I need is to find all TypeB objects that has the LowerB value greater than the UpperB value for each of the String keys in the Map defined above. I have a vague idea of how to do this, but somehow messing it up with the return types:

1. Check if the map1 and map2 is not empty
2. map1.map and for each key in map1, get the values from map2
3. zip the map1 and map2 values and collect all LowerB that is greater than UpperB

The problem is that at step 2, what should I do for case None? This is messing my return types. Any suggestions?

Comment: Extending case classes is either not possible or not good practice.

Comment: Can you give a small example of input/expected output? I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can implement step 2, as well as zip values like this:

```
val r = map1.map{ case (k1, v1) => v1 zip map2.getOrElse(k1, List[TypeA]()) }

// returns Iterable[List[(TypeA, TypeA)]]
```